# Como exibir no ListView um único dado de uma query que retorna dois dados?

Tags: android, listview

Tenho uma *query* que retorna o nome e o sobrenome de uma pessoa. Com o resultado desta *query*, eu insiro as informações dentro de um `ListView` e é exibido o nome e o sobrenome.

Como faço para exibir somente o nome?

E depois eu teria que usar a string nome usando o `arraAdapter.getItem(position);` mas pegar também somente o nome, não poderia vir o sobrenome.

Obs: Infelizmente não posso alterar a *query*, ele deve retornar o nome e o sobrenome mesmo, também não posso usar `CursorAdapter` na *query*.

Comment: Poste o código para que as respostas possam ser concisas.

Comment: Uma dúvida. "Nome" e "Sobrenome" são colunas separadas da tabela ou você salva o nome completo da pessoa em uma coluna "Nome Completo"?

Comment: Nome e Sobrenome são colunas separadas.

Comment: Sem ver o código e dada as limitações que vc descreveu, vc pode usar o método [split()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java) de String e pegar a substring na posição 0. Daí não sei se ignorar o segundo nome de pessoas com nome composto é um problema pro seu caso

Answer (score 1):

Você pode separar o nome pelos espaços usando `.split();`, ele vai separar sua string em um array de acordo com o campo separador que você informar como parâmetro.

Exemplo para solucionar seu problema:

```
String nomeCompleto= "JOÃO DA SILVA";  
String array[] = nomeCompleto.split(" "); 
String primeiroNome = array[0];
```